# htaccess redirect if domain matches with multiple exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have two domains pointed to the same domain directory.
domain1.com
sub.domain2.com

I want all requests coming to sub.domain2.com to be redirected to domain1.com with the exceptions :

- sub.domain2.com/exception1/(:any)
- sub.domain2.com/exception2/(:any)
- sub.domain2.com/exception3/(:any)

Is it possible to do it with .htaccess?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception1/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception2/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception3/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Comment: IT Worked!
Also, what if i want to make an exception for the root too, what do i add?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]`